# How to customize<input type="color">?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, sass

In  styles I want replace standard icon with custom svg icon. Is it possible via css/js?

I tried add a background-image, but old rectangle doesnt dissapear

HTML:

```html
<input type="color" id="color-input" value="#563d7c" title="Choose your color">
```

CSS:

```css
#color-input {
  background-image: url("https://www.svgrepo.com/show/439108/color-theory.svg");
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Tried to add a padding, and it works!
CSS now:

```css
#color-input {
  background-image: url("https://www.svgrepo.com/show/439108/color-theory.svg");
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

(standart color icon doesnt dissapear without padding. Still if you have more wise solution, I want to see that.
Thank you all. I made it thanks to all of you!

Comment: What icon are you referring to? You can customize this in various ways, such as removing the border and padding, changing the width and height, the background color, etc. I'm not aware of an icon associated with input type color or what an SVG icon would be used for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Label` for your input and put your svg as `<img>` in the html. Watch the snippet below:

```css
input[type=color] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="color-picker">
   <input type="color" id="color-input" value="#563d7c" title="Choose your color">
   <label class="color-select" for="color-input"><img width="42px" height="42px" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/439108/color-theory.svg"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your code? Otherwise if what you are trying to do is insert an svg icon you can do something like this:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

Also doing it this way is easier than doing it through styles. Is there a particular reason you want to do it in styles? Your other option is to convert the svg into a png and use it as a background image.
You can use the following page for that: https://svgtopng.com/

Answer (score 0):

It works with padding in css

```css
#color-input {
  background-image: url("https://www.svgrepo.com/show/439108/color-theory.svg");
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 20px;
}
```